# Can OpenCL directly put pixel on the screen?

Tags: winapi, opencl

I'm trying to make a 3D voxel based game only with WinAPI and OpenCL to make all the computations on the device-side.

Right now, at each frame, I'm transferring the framebuffer from the device to the host and then use StretchDiBits function.
But I saw that this process is slow and decrease my frame rate so **I would like to directly display the pixels on the screen from the device-side.**
I don't want to use OpenGL or other 3D libraries.

Comment: I doubt that you can avoid a call to [`clCreateFromGLTexture`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromGLTexture.html), and using OpenGL for display.